# Symfony2: Error with Doctrine only in production env

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, development-environment, production-environment

I have one problem in production env.

When I insert one row in one table with doctrine:

```
        ...
        $Download = new Downloads();
        $Download->setToken($token);       
        $Download->setValid($now); 
        $em->persist($Download);
        ...
```

In Dev env there isn't problem, but in Production env my primary key ($token) doesn't store. His value is empty in the database (in dev env store rights).

My table only has two fields:

```
 /**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(name="token", type="string", length=45, nullable=false)
 */
private $token;

 /**
 * @var valid
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="valid", type="integer", nullable=false)
 */
private $valid;

/**
 * Set token
 *
 * @param string $token
 * @return Downloads
 */
public function setToken($token)
{
    $this->token = $token;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get token
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getToken()
{
    return $this->token;
}

/**
 * Set valid
 *
 * @param integer $valid
 * @return Downloads
 */
public function setValid($valid)
{
    $this->valid = $valid;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get valid
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getValid()
{
    return $this->valid;
}
```

Somebody can help me?
Thanks!

Comment: Please show the error you obtained.

Comment: The error is that the primary key is empty in my database in Prod env

Comment: Please add the mapping of this entity in your question.

Comment: You can see my entity, it's very simple class

Comment: I didn't know Doctrine2 accepts a string as a primary key. Are you sure `$token` is not empty?

Comment: yes, in Dev ENV all is right and the db it's the same. In Prod ENV when I do $em->flush disappear the value of $token

Comment: Is the code of your insertion even called in prod env?

Comment: Yes, this code is for all env